# Soundmanager will not play a sound

Tags: javascript, wav, soundmanager2

```
function doclick(){  
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'mySound',
        url: 'http://localhost/htmlshooter/wav/gun.wav',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        volume: 100
    });

    mySound.play();
}
```

First it says:

> SMSound._onload(): "mySound" failed to load? - http://localhost/htmlshooter/wav/gun.wav
>   SMSound.play(): "mySound" is starting to play
>   SMSound.play(): "mySound" is loading - attempting to play..

And then:

> soundManager.createSound(): mySound exists
>   soundManager.createSound(): mySound (http://localhost/htmlshooter/wav/gun.wav)

But in fact, its not playing any sound at all.

Comment: Does the sound file you specified exist at that location? The first error message said it failed to load. Can you play it in your browser (the same URL)?

Comment: @pavium yes, its http://localhost/htmlshooter/wav/gun.wav

Comment: Well, I could see that from the question ... if you can play it by typing the URL in the browser we can discount my first thought - that the error message said the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think Soundmanager2 plays Wav files. You could try enabling HTML5 support on SM2 maybe?

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't find this simple explanation anywhere. I defaulted all browsers without HTML MP3 support to use WAV files. I had to add the exception to HTML4 browsers to also use MP3 files.